# UITextField ellipses

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitextfield

I have a UITextField but when it overflows I want it to **scroll** not use an ellipses.  Can you do this on the iPhone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put your text field into a `UIScrollView` with a large content size....  This would make it scrollable.